# How to add a xaml page/usercontrol to a windows form control?

Tags: c#, xaml

so basically what I am trying to do is create an input form in XAML, and add it to a panel in my C# wpf program.

What I am trying is:

```
Page pg = new Page();
Panel pnl = new Panel();

pnl.Controls.Add(pg);
```

But it gives me an error saying that it cannot convert a Page to Control...

I have tried the same thing with a xaml UserControl, with the same error.

Is there a way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

[Page is a root element](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752059.aspx#xaml_root_elements_and_xaml_namespaces), you can't add any parent elements to a Page object.  Also make sure to define an XML namespace to go with that Page element.

I think you're imagining it in the wrong terms.  Think of the Page element as the encompassing web page itself.  A page can be divided into panels which control the layout of the page itself.

Also keep in mind that the Panel class itself is only a [base class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754152.aspx#Panels_view_from_10000_feet).  Use one of the derived classes in order to get the layout you want.

Comment: so I cant add a page to a panel is what you are saying? :( I wouldnt actually write just Page pg = new Page(), I would have a .xaml file which has the Page class in it...i just wrote it like that up there cause I thought it would be easiest to read like that

Comment: so I can add a panel to a page, but not the other way around?

Comment: Yep.  Any specific reason you want a page element within a panel?  There is most definitely some other element that can accomplish the same task.